# Graph Search API order by like fql

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there a way to sort the result with the Graph api by key? and choose desc or asc? 
just like in fql?

in the FQL I perform my query for event with ORDER BY start_time ASC at the end

anything similar in the graph api?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's currently no way to sort the results of Graph API calls, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1#reading

In the most cases, the results are returned in the order of the creation time though.

Comment: i Guess it will be available in the future

Comment: Well Graph API still does not provide this option! And In the most cases, the results are returned in the order of the updated time. This makes certain apps like mine to filter it manually on my end, which is sometimes a pain because some very old (but freshly updated) posts show up in the feed. Anyway there is still no way around this.

Answer (score 0):

Currently in version 2.10 I can say that you can not even do the ordering of data in the API Graph facebook, a solution to this could be to sort the data from the frontend of the app with an external library.