# Is it possible to get facebook posts using koala gem in ascending order?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, koala-gem

I can get public pages posts. However, they are in descending order - the very latest post is the first one I get - and I want to get them in ascending order. So, Is that possible?

```
posts = @@graph.get_connections(page_name, node_type, limit: posts_limit,fields: 'id,message,created_time,updated_time,shares,comments.summary(true).limit(0)')
```

Comment: I don't think facebook let's you query the posts API specifying an order. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25774885/graph-seach-api-order-by-like-fql

Comment: I want to set a break-point to start over pulling posts if the connection is out or something. any suggestions?

Comment: I've never used Koala, but a quick look at the repo will show you how to retrieve posts from a given point. `#get_connection` takes an option `:since` . https://github.com/arsduo/koala/blob/2742f9286e87dd087185530da6e1add5fac35f80/lib/koala/api/graph_collection.rb